# Filling array by cells from different sheets

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a beginner question in VBA. Im trying to make a loop to fill an array by phone numbers located at 12 different sheets. When I do the bellow code its only stores the values of first sheet.

```
   For J = 1 To 12

   For i = i To UBound(ArrayPhone)

     ArrayPhone(i) = Range("P" & i + 2).Value

    Next

Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select

Next
```

As how I can prevent from storing empty values in the array.

I’d be greatful for any clues as to what I’m doing wrong.

Comment: It actually can get quite complicated if you don't know exactly how many numbers you'll put into the array from the get go. [Here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/VBAArrays.htm) is a link that can show you how to do what you want to do. Look at the `InsertElementIntoArray` part.

Answer (score 1):

You are always writing into the array starting from position `i = 1` for each sheet. This means that your outer loop iterating over sheets is useless.

You would need to size the array appropriately to hold all numbers from all sheets, and then add a counter which counts how many items you've already put into the array.